# I can’t unscrew the rear tire dust cap and when I pump it not all the air from the pump goes in

Tags: tire, tire-pressure, rear

It is a Kent Ambush FS20 bike. Blue. Pretty Old around 5-7 years old.

---

[image]

<sub>From https://www.walmart.com/ip/Kent-Bicycles-20-Boy-s-Ambush-BMX-Child-Bike-Black-Blue/36877058</sub>

Comment: Welcome to the site :  I'm not sure what you're asking - you can't get the dust cap off the valve on your rear wheel, and somehow when you pump not all the air goes into the tyre (with the dust cap on?) ?    It might help to add a photo of your valve to the question using [edit]       Perhaps you're looking at a presta valve where the nut loosens but doesn't come off?

Comment: Is the basic question “How can I remove an air valve dust cap that is too tight?”

Comment: It helps to have a brief title and the actual question in the post, with more explanation of what exactly you are asking. if your question is "how do I pump my tyre with the dust cap on, the answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 0):

I've added a stock photo of this bike - it appears to have Schrader aka AV valves, same as a car.   So the dust cap should absolutely twist off in an anticlockwise direction.

You may need to hold the stem with pliers and twist the cap with a second pair of pliers.